# Javascript don't work on ajax generated part

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a little problem with ajax generated part - javascript don't work on this generated part.
There is ajax call:

```
<script>
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  $("#preloadmore").show();
  if ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() + 350 >= $(document).height()) {
    //AJAX
    var idlast = 256;
    $.ajax({
      url: "ajax/loadmore.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        id: idlast
      },
      success: function(result) {
        if (result != "") {
          $("#preloadmore").hide();
          $("#loadmore").html(result);
        } else
          alert("Error 504");
      }
    });
  }

});
</script>
```

In body I have part to display ajax result:

```
<div id="loadmore"></div>
```

When ajax input content in loadmore div, javascript don't work on this part.
There is jquery - don't work:

```
 $('.rating').on('rating.change', function(event, value, caption) {
    alert('Test');
 });
```

Thanks

Comment: You should [delegate event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) if this custom event bubbles...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite grasp how `.rating` is related to the 2 code snippets before it. Anyways, I hope I got your problem right.

```
// I assume your .rating field is dynamically loaded inside #loadmore
$('#loadmore').on('change', '.rating', function(e){
    alert('Test');
    alert( $(this).val() );
});

// If your .rating field already exists, then try this
$('.rating').on('change', function(event) {
    alert('Test');
    alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: He loads the .rating input field into #loadmore (snippet 2) using ajax (snippet 1); that's how it's related.

Comment: @sgtdck yeah I assumed so. Thanks. Added 2 versions. 1st snippet should be the answer if it's the case.

Comment: Thanks, you are awesome :)